# How do I use subplot to plot everything from an imported .fig file (while preserving legend+axes+labels)?

Tags: matlab, plot

Here are the list of commands I have done to try to place an external figure (both figures listed at http://www.atmos.uw.edu/~akchen0/CERES_Project/) into a `subplot` slot in an open figure.

```
subplot(2,2,1);
a = open('blah.fig');
plot(a);
```

I'd like `blah.fig` to be subplot 1, but I only get an error message when I try to "plot" a.

Tried the listed solution from the answer, but it didn't print out any of the labels/legends (and a few of the graphs are missing) - the results are roughly shown below.

```
copyobj(findobj('type','line'),s1)
```

allows me to copy all the lines fine (though they're distorted a bit). If I want to try copying the legend with

```
copyobj(findobj(gcf1,'Type','axes','Tag','legend'),s1)
```

It does not work, and displays the error message "Object axes[1](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-9a2ca5bc730c68c3c505288d4357ea2a?convert_to_webp=true) can not be a child of parent axes[1](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-9a2ca5bc730c68c3c505288d4357ea2a?convert_to_webp=true)". If I use ax1, it displays "invalid handle". Same for the command below:

```
copyobj(findobj('type','axes'),s1)
```

[image: http://puu.sh/8S50L.png]

Some links I tried but didn't work:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92538-how-can-i-copy-an-existing-figure-onto-another-figure-as-a-subplot-using-matlab-7-10-r2010a

Or this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/108304

```
>> figure_children = get(gcf1,'Children');
children_axes = findall(figure_children,'Type','axes');
>> copyobj(children_axes,s1)
Error using copyobj
Object axes[1] can not be a child of parent axes[1]
```

[allchild](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/85219-subplot-of-already-saved-figures) does not work either.

```
>> copyobj(allchild(h1),s1)
Error using copyobj
Object uicontextmenu[1] can not be a child of parent axes[1]
```

The second reply [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/jr2DgValmQs) works for its own example but not for my example.

Answer (score 3):

In order to copy MATLAB figure (`.fig`) files, here are the steps you need to follow.

1. First open them up with `openfig` and use the `reuse` flag.  This ensures that you don't reload the figures if they're already open.
2. Make sure you get the current axes for all these loaded figures.
3. Make a new figure, then get a handle for each `subplot` slot you want.
4. Grab all of the children elements from the handles to the axes of each figure you loaded in from file.
5. Use `copyobj` to copy the figures using the children elements from Step #4 into each `subplot` slot using the `subplot` handles.

In other words, take a look at this example:

```
% /// Step #1 and #2
h1 = openfig('test1.fig','reuse'); %// open figure from file
ax1 = gca; % // get handle to axes of figure

h2 = openfig('test2.fig','reuse'); %// open another figure from file
ax2 = gca; % // get handle to axes of the other figure

%// test1.fig and test2.fig are the names of the figure files which you would 
%// like to copy into multiple subplots

% /// Step #3
h3 = figure; %// create new figure
s1 = subplot(2,1,1); % // create and get handle to the subplot axes
s2 = subplot(2,1,2);

% /// Step #4
fig1 = get(ax1,'children'); %// get handle to all the children in the figure
fig2 = get(ax2,'children');

% /// Step #5
copyobj(fig1,s1); %// copy children to new parent axes i.e. the subplot axes
copyobj(fig2,s2);
```

Comment: Wow - thanks! I just tried that and it didn't work very well though (screenshot is here: http://puu.sh/8Qz1l.png ) The title isn't preserved, and neither are many of the multiple graphs.

Comment: @InquilineKea: Ahhh... ok if there are legends and labels involved... then I have to modify my solution.  You'll have to give me a little bit.  BTW, your screenshot is confusing.  Which graph am I supposed to look at?  Can you provide your `.fig` file so I can try and reproduce the problem myself?  I'm using R2014a so I'm pretty sure I'll be able to load it in.

Comment: @InquilineKea: Sorry buddy!  I gotta go eat.  Hope someone else can figure this out in the meantime.

Comment: Okay sure - that's fine. :) Do you think you could work it out now?